# Jquery Droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

following is my jquery Code I can access the `gallery-folder` properties by jquery object but droppable isn't working on it

```
$(function() {
        jQuery(document).find('#am-container').find('img').draggable({revert: true});
        jQuery(document).find("#gallary-folder").droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                var draggableSrc = ui.draggable.attr("src");
                var gallery_id = $(this).find('li').attr("id");
            }
        });
    });
```

Following is my HTML

```
 <div id="gallery-folder" class="gallery-folder ui-droppable">
    <div class="gallery-folder-inner">
     <a href="gallery_view.php?id=22&gallery_name=Clothes123">
      <img width="68" height="48" src="images/icon-2.png"> </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gV7da/4/

Comment: Any reason you're using `jQuery(document).find('#ele')` instead of `$('#ele')`?

Comment: @Wex: I assume they are same so, thats a reason why i stick to old school

Comment: Your fiddle has `revert: "true"` where it should be (as you wrote in your question) `revert: true` (no quotes around `true`). Then, as long as you comment out the `saveImageAfterDrag` call that is not defined and throws an error, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @noobie-php Just $('#ele') is one less function call, therefore faster - even if marginally so. Running $(document) creates a jQuery object from the DOM element 'document' and all of its children, whereas $('#ele') creates one for the DOM element with ID 'ele' and all its children. Your way (from my understanding so anyone correct me if I'm wrong) is longer because the find() function then has to iterate through all of the objects in $(document) until it finds 'ele'. I think you're getting mixed up with document.getElementById('ele')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw your fiddle. That's working fine. You are probably unable to really drop your image to the target.

Means you need to drag centre of your draggable object to within the bounds of target obeject. And it must work :)